# Cannot scp Over a Shared Connection

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, bash-scripting, openssh

I am having the following problem with an SSH shared connection:

```
# Set up a shared connection
ssh -f -N -M -S "$SSH_CONTROL_SOCKET" root@"$ONE_HOST"

# I can scp *without* the shared connection
scp root@"$ONE_HOST":/etc/hosts /dev/null

# I can execute a remote command *with* the shared connection
ssh -S "$SSH_CONTROL_SOCKET" root@"$ONE_HOST" "date"

# But I can't scp *with* the shared connection
scp -vvv -S "$SSH_CONTROL_SOCKET" root@"$ONE_HOST":/etc/hosts .
```

This script gives this output:

```
hosts                                                              100%   59    67.8KB/s   00:00
Wed Feb 28 08:23:10 MST 2018
Executing: program /home/myUser/ssh_sharing_socket host myHost.example.com, user root, command scp -v -f /etc/hosts
/home/myUser/ssh_sharing_socket: Permission denied
```

My SSH shared connection is authenticated using a public key and an SSH agent.

What must I do to be able to scp over a shared connection?

Comment: What is an example value of $SSH_CONTROL_SOCKET?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`ssh` and `scp` use the `-S` option for different purposes.

[`ssh`](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh#S):

> **-S** ctl_path
>   Specifies the location of a control socket for connection sharing, or the string “none” to disable connection sharing. Refer to the description of ControlPath and ControlMaster in ssh_config(5) for details.

[`scp`](https://man.openbsd.org/scp#S):

> **-S** program
>   Name of program to use for the encrypted connection. The program must understand ssh(1) options.

You're getting the error "Permission denied" because `scp` is trying to run the control socket as a program.

For scp, you should use the option [`-o ControlPath=/path/to/socket`](https://man.openbsd.org/scp#o):

```
scp -vvv -o "ControlPath=$SSH_CONTROL_SOCKET" root@"$ONE_HOST":/etc/hosts .
```